# Installing EOS using command docker pull eosio/eos:v1.4.2

Tags: installation

On a clean mac, I tried to install EOS with the command "docker pull eosio/eos:v1.4.2" from the developer's website and I received the error:

```
Error response from daemon: manifest for eosio/eos:1.4.2 not found
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, there is a missing bit in the settings of that docker.
On a clean computer with no previous docker the easy workaround is to start the docker pull with the previous version, stop it after it starts and then it will work.

```
docker pull eosio/eos:v1.3.2
```

Wait a few seconds and stop it with control+c

```
^c
```

Now the original command should work:

```
docker pull eosio/eos:v1.4.2
```

Comment: Thank you for the prompt reply.  Let me follow your instructions and then provide you feedback

Comment: Whoop!  Your instructions worked.  Docker image is downloading successfully.  Thanks again!